# GRE calc III spherical coordinate

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck on the set up of this triple integral, am I doing it correcT?

Compute the volume of the unit sphere contained between meridians $\phi =30^{\circ}$ and $60^{\circ}$ and between parallels $\theta=45^{\circ}$ and $\theta=60^{\circ}$.

I have attempted the following spherical triple integral set up, but I got it incorrect. What am I doing wrong ?

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{-1}^1 \rho^2 \sin \phi d \rho d \theta d \phi.$$

What Am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why does $ \ \rho \ $ run from $ \ -1  $ (?!) to $ \ 1 \ $ ?

Comment: should it be $0$ to $1$? I was thinking it had to be either that or $-1,1$. @boojum

Comment: $ \ \rho \ $ is distance _from the origin_ ("center of coordinates").  The polar angle $ \ \phi \ $ and the azimuthal angle $ \ \theta \ $ will have different values in the opposite octant.  So, yes, $ \ \rho \ $ should be "starting" from $ \ 0 \ \ . $  Another problem:  your angle variables are swapped relative to the problem's specifications.  (This is a common difficulty between the way mathematicians and physicists write spherical coordinates; you have the mathematicians' version in your integral, but the problem is using the physicists' convention.)

Comment: Oh, and in the integrand, that should be $ \ \mathbf{\rho^2} \ \ . $

Comment: ahhh thanks! I think I got it!

Comment: @boojum so my $\theta$ and $\phi$ are off?

Comment: I'm saying that your integrand is set up correctly for the way mathematicians define the angular variables.  But the problem is calling the polar angle $ \ \theta \ $ (for the "parallels"), which is what physicists do.  For your integral, $ \ \phi \ $ needs to run from $ \ \pi/4 \ $  to $ \ \pi/3 \ \ . $ (I could tell this because your sine factor is $ \ \sin \phi \ \ . ) $  The "meridians" (lines of "longitude") are for azimuthal angle, which you are calling $ \ \theta \ \ , $ but the problem calls $ \ \phi \ \ . $  Beware of this on the exam and in future courses!